# why $ sAs^{-1}= A?$ where $A=\{1,r,r^2,r^3\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

In Dummit and Foote book Page No : $50$  example $3$

It is written that  $$N_{D_8}(A)=D_8$$   where
$A=\{1,r,r^2,r^3\}\subseteq D_8$

**My confusion** : By the definition  of normalizer we have $ sAs^{-1}= A$
But  here $srs^{-1}=r^{-1}ss^{-1} =r^{-1} \neq r$

i,e $srs^{-1}\neq r$ , so there is a contradiction to  $ sAs^{-1}= A$

Therefore $$N_{D_8}(A) \neq D_8$$

why  $ sAs^{-1}= A?$

Comment: But $r^{-1}=r^3\in A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that $sAs^{-1} = A$ does not imply that $srs^{-1} = r$, even though $r \in A$. The equality $sAs^{-1} = A$ means that the map $f : x \mapsto sxs^{-1}$ defined on $A$ has image $A$. In this case, $f(1) = 1$ and $f(r^2) = r^2$, but $f(r) = r^{-1}$ and $f(r^{-1}) = r$.

Hope this answers your question.